# Custom font face not requested by browsers

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face

I know that questions with similar titles already exist, but after reading them, I'm still stuck.

I'm developing a website using `Django` and serving static files (css and js) with no problem using `{% static %}` tag. I wanted to use a custom font so put this style tag in my base template. (and it ends up in `<head>` of the page the way I expect.)

```html
<style>
    @font-face {
        font-family: IRANSansX !important;
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 400;
        src: url({% static 'css/fonts/IRANSansX-Regular.woff2' %}) format('woff2'); /* final value -> url(/static/css/fonts/IRANSansX-Regular.woff2)*/
    }

    body {
        font-family: IRANSansX, sans-serif;
    }
</style>
```

To my surprise, nothing happened. In both Chrome and Firefox, the browser don't event send the request to download the font. I did several checks:

- I tested and saw that Django serves the font if I manually create a url by appending the value of `url()` to my website domain.
- I tried to apply the font to other elements, no success.
- I tried `''` and `""` for my font-family name and the url, no success.
- I tried another font, no success.

It's strange that `bootstrap-icons.woff2` font, which is also of type woff2, is working properly and is loaded by browsers. The only difference is that, it's relatively addressed by `bootstrap-icons.css` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was all to `!important` at the end of `font-family` definition. I removed it and everything worked!

It's strange that if `!important` is not a part of the font-face and actually breaks its functionality, how come my IDE (Pycharm) didn't even trigger a warning.